# Where can I buy the microphones that they use the Oscars and Grammys?

Tags: microphone, microphone-technique, microphone-positioning, microphone-stand

Where can I buy the microphones that they use at the Oscars and Grammys?
And what are the microphone mounts and stands called? Do they have a specific name?
I don't necessary need the precise one that the oscars has, but as long at they look similar, a double mounted microphone with a foam cover.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Never seen before. Usually we se double Schoeps (two tubes). Like to find out as well.

Answer (score 0):

Shures are often used at these shows for performances: https://www.shure.com/en-US/about-us/press/shure-captures-the-sound-of-music-icons-at-the-65th-grammy-r-awards

More details on the podium Schoeps: https://forums.prosoundweb.com/index.php?topic=84083.0

Answer (score 0):

All or most of the big name awards shows use Schoeps microphones on custom presenter stands.  Typically there are two capsules, a cardioid and a hypercardioid.  The preamps are remotely mounted at the base and the whole thing mounted into a custom stand made by ATK (Audiotek).  The one we use mostly are wireless.  Two custom battery powered preamps are fitted into the base along with two Senneheiser wireless beltpacks.  This allows us to place these where needed and pull them clear of performances and particular camera shots. Of course the wireless version is easily converted to a hardwire position. This rig is also fitted into a fixed mechanism that allows the mics to disappear into the stage and telescope to match the presenters height perfectly.  This is known as the "pop up mic".  I am currently on an awards show where we have 3 RF setups.